# Delete several columns at once in Python 3 using Openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl

After loading a file I am trying to delete 2 columns, but every time delete 1 column, the index of the next column I am trying to delete changes so I have to use index-1. No problem if it's only 2 columns but if I have to be deleting several columns, how can I do it all at once?

```
for file in files:
fileName = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
if fileName == 'Any file name':
    wb = load_workbook(file)
    sheet = wb.active
    # Delete the first 3 rows
    sheet.delete_rows(1, 3)
    # Delete Column G
    sheet.delete_cols(7)
    # Delete Column L
    sheet.delete_cols(12)
    workbook.save(file)
```

Should I use something different like numpy or work with everything using DataFrames?

Comment: Your best option is to delete columns from right-to-left as this means that the indices don't change.

Answer (score 2):

You could delete the values starting with the rightmost index instead. For example to remove the 0th, 1st, and 2nd indices from a list:

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> del x[2]
>>> del x[1]
>>> del x[0]
>>> x
[3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Compare that result with your method, which deletes from left to right:

```
>>> x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> del x[0]
>>> del x[1]
>>> del x[2]
>>> x
[1, 3, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

If the dependency isn't too heavy I would recommend using pandas for this. Pandas has a `read_excel` function that uses Openpyxl under the hood and working with Pandas DataFrames is generally ergonomic and there are far more resources online (and answered stack overflow questions) for most issues you may run into.

```
import pandas as pd

for file in files:
    fileName = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
    if fileName == 'Any file name':
        df = pd.read_excel(file)

        # Delete the first 3 rows
        df = df.drop([0, 1, 2], axis = 0)
        df = df.drop([7, 12])
        # Or if your excel file is labeled
        # df = df.drop(["G", "L"])
        df.write_excel(fileName)
```